# why its showing empty path didnt match any of these

Tags: django

Using the URLconf defined in My_Ecom_Project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
account/
^static/(?P.*)$
^media/(?P.*)$
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: Because non of the paths you defined matches for the `/` path.

Comment: Why did you expect it to match any path?

Comment: hi.. im a beginner i dont know why its showing like this..if i run the server in cmd its not showing any errors but i cannot able to open the webpage..

Comment: because the view you are trying to open simply does not exists. You never specified a path what to do when you visit `/`. This is actually no error from the server, strictly speaking it is the browser that tries to visit a non-existing page.

Comment: i checked urls.py and settings..still im confused what am i doing wrong

Comment: sir, actually it was my mistake for not specifying a path..thanks again for ur reply..

Answer (score 0):

Add a path with the urlpattern being `'/'`.  You can also use `''` if your webserver handles stripping final slashes. As @Willem Van Onsem mentions you're simply not handling the path you're webserver is passing to Django.

Comment: thanks for ur reply..actually it was my mistake for not specifying a particular path..